# Memory access monitor for c programs

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

I am trying to track down memory accesses to heap allocated memory.

For example, if I have the following code:

```
void set_value(int* buffer, size_t pos, int value) {
    buffer[pos] = value;
}
int main(void) {    
    int* buffer = malloc(BUFF_SIZE * sizeof(int));
    set_value(buffer, 2, 10);
    set_value(buffer, 3, 12);

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I am mainly interested in the functions that access the memory and the address of the content that have been modified.

I have tried to use multiple memory tools like **ptrace**, **strace**, **ASan**, **Dmalloc**, but I didn't achieve the result.

Another idea was to modify the memory change the protection of the memory using **mprotect** and writing the handlers for Page Faults. I made the memory read-only and when a write occurs, the handler modifies the page protection and let the function to write the content in memory, but after that I cannot made the page read only again, for futher accesses.

Do you have any tips on how to monitor every write made to the heap memory?

Comment: Using `gdb`, you can set a hardware breakpoint on the address. GDB calls them *watchpoint*s. As far as I'm aware, on x86 platform, you have a limit of 4 watchpoints, but this may have been an implementation detail? I'm not 100% sure on that one. See https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html

Comment: Have you considered using `memcmp()` ?  For the blocks you wish to monitor you could keep a _copy_, then periodically check that the mem location of interest still matches its copy.  `memcmp(copy, location, len_location);`

Comment: Please provide a little more detail.  Are you interested in run-time notifications from _within_ your application,  or by using an external tool, or is the debug method mentioned in the comments sufficient?  _[DMalloc](http://dmalloc.com/docs/latest/online/dmalloc_7.html)_ publishes capabilities that appear to match perfectly what you have described as your requirements.  So what exactly did not work with DMalloc?

Comment: What operating system you are using?

Comment: @IvanAngelov I am using Ubuntu 14.04, but I am interested how you can do this on both Linux and Windows environment. I have decided to start with Ubuntu because I have prior experience with it.

Comment: @ryyker I would prefer to have an external tool that would push notifications or log into a file any time a write is being made in a memory chunk that I specify.  Modifying the source file would also be an option, but not the one that I prefer.

Comment: @ryyker [DMalloc](http://dmalloc.com/), from what I understood and was able to create with it, can help you log statistics about unconsistency of heap or illegal accesses. I would like my application to monitor both legal and illegal writes.
Basically, every time a dynamically allocated memory zone is being written, my application should log that into a file.

Comment: @FlorinAvram - Just to be clear, Are you desiring to _write_ a utility to do what you've described, or be pointed to one that exists already?  My assumption, from what you've said, is that you would like to develop your own, (just want to make sure)

Comment: If I am wrong (i.e., you do not want to write your own) then for Windows only , SysInternals _[VMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx)_ may be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to monitor every memory access, I'd suggest to take a look at the packages such as PIN [1] and/or DynInst [2]. Both are dynamic binary instrumentation packages that allow you to modify an application binary to inject the code you want. In this case, both tools allow you to instrument every single instruction and know the address they reference (if they are loads/stores). Then, if you're only interested in memory allocated by malloc (or realloc, or calloc) you can also instrument these routines to capture their entry parameters and exit values to determine the region of memory of interest. Both tools provide similar functionalities. I'd say that their main difference is that PIN specifically focuses to Intel processors while DynInst is an open source project that supports different processor architectures (Intel, IBM-Power, ARM).

Since instrumentation may be costly in this particular scenario that instruments every instruction and you can afford to sample memory references, I'd suggest you to explore the PEBS infrastructure [3] from recent Intel processors (AMD processors have something similar named IBS). PEBS can be used from the perf tool available within the Linux OS [4] (I don't know if it is available on other OSeS)

[1] PIN https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool

[2] DynInst http://www.dyninst.org

[3] Intel Manual Section 18.4.4 Precise Event Based Sampling (PEBS) http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3b-part-2-manual.pdf

[4] Linux perf to sample memory addresses https://lwn.net/Articles/531766/

Answer (score 0):

The better tool to do this purpose is by exploiting the new feature in all modern processors so-called Hardware Performance Counter. To access theses counters, you need a special API and I recommended PAPI to you (PAPI: Performance API). It provides a huge functions to access these counters and to measure all micro-architecture events such as, cache his, miss, floating-point operations and so more.